# RequestHeaders.IfMatch is empty, but RequestHeaders.Headers contains "If-Match" key/value pair

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, etag

I'm making a http request, and set the `If-Match` header like so..

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "00000000E0D09CA0");
```

The I post the request to the api service. On the other end I receive the request and attempt to get the `If-Match` header like so..

```
RequestHeaders requestHeaders = this.HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders();
var ifMatchValue = requestHeaders.IfMatch?.FirstOrDefault()?.Tag.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

Frustratingly, this returns an empty string. If I debug I can see the `requestHeaders.IfMatch` is indeed an empty array. However the `requestHeaders.Headers` contains (amongst other header values) a key/value pair with an "If-Match" key and the expected value.

Why is my attempt to get this from the `IfMatch` property failing?

Answer (score 0):

The `If-Match` value must be sent with quote characters `"` surrounding the actual value you want to send.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "\"00000000E0D09CA0\"");
```